# What networking libraries/frameworks exist for Python?

Tags: python, networking, frameworks

I was wondering what good networking libraries/frameworks there are for Python.

Please provide a link to the standard API documentation for the library, and perhaps a link to a decent tutorial to get started with it.

A comment or two about its advantages/disadvantages would be nice as well.

Comment: Many, many similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+networking+library

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441849/good-python-networking-libraries-for-building-a-tcp-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) framework. The advantage:

- solid reactor implementation
- support for almost all network protocols found in the wild
- well documented

Disadvantages:

- it's *huge*
- the asynchronous APIs need some time to get used to (but once you are familiar, things are actually pretty usable)

CPython itself ships with a tiny [reactor/socket package](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html). Never used it myself, though.

Comment: twisted is not huge, that's a misconception I can't get where it came from. I just added the size of .py files in my twisted copy and got only 9.7MB. That is **very small** , considering that most hard drives being sold today are >= 500GB. Even cell phones have this easily available. And for less than 10MB, I got support to almost every protocol found in the wild. I could remove parts of it to make it smaller but it is hardly worth the few MB I would save. Please clarify what you mean with *huge* .

Comment: That's pretty large in terms of the time it would take to code or understand it, the number of functions it provides, or the number of subtly different ways you could use it.

Comment: Huge as in vast, not necessarily huge as in file size.  The library can be stripped down by just about any optimizer if disk space is actually an issue.

Answer (score 6):

The standard library has [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) which is good for very simple stuff as well as the [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html) stuff if you'd prefer something that does threads.  There's also [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) but the barrier of entry to that is a bit high if you're not used to event-driven IO.  If you're after web frameworks, [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) is a good start or there's [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [TurboGears](http://turbogears.org/) if you're looking for something more full-featured.

Answer (score 3):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) is the most complete, and complex, of all Python networking frameworks.

It's well-established and very complete, but it has a steep learning curve.

[Documentation here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation); [FAQ here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to build/manipulate your own packets there is Scapy too :)

The usage is pretty straight forward, it lets you do whatever you want with the packets
and it's multi-Platform.

Project Page: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/

Docs: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/

Example: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html